# Customize redundant Checkbox input Jquery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this working code bellow and i think he is a little bit too long and redundant can i customize it ?

```
$( "#unique" ).click(function() {

    if ( $( this ).is(':checked') ) {
        $( ".lotud" ).show();
        $( "#add_lot" ).hide();
        $( "#lots_rows_contnr" ).hide();

        $(".lotud input").prop({disabled: false})
        $("#lots_rows_contnr input").prop({disabled: true})
    }
    else {
        $( ".lotud" ).hide();
        $( "#add_lot" ).show();
        $( "#lots_rows_contnr" ).show();

        $(".lotud input").prop({disabled: true})
        $("#lots_rows_contnr input").prop({disabled: false})
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shorten it slightly through the use of ternaries, using the `checked` property on the DOMElement itself, joining selectors and using the `checked` property as the basis for the `disabled` property. Try this:

```
$("#unique").click(function() {
    $(".lotud").toggle(this.checked);
    $("#add_lot, #lots_rows_contnr").toggle(!this.checked);
    $(".lotud input").prop({ disabled: !this.checked });
    $("#lots_rows_contnr input").prop({ disabled: this.checked });
});
```

Which of the two versions, your original or the above, is more readable is a matter of opinion.

Comment: thanks @Rory i undestand now your approch ;) me too i don't understand why the downvote because i have a working code and i want just to customize it